# SELECT COUNT SQLSERVER

Tags: select, count

estou tentando fazer um select com count para trazer o total de manifesto agrupadas por Placa do carro e o Mes, porém ele traz uma contagem unica não agrupando...
Onde estou errando?

O select que estou usando:

```
SELECT 
      R.PLACA   
    , MONTH(R.DATEMI) AS [MES]
    , COUNT(*) AS [TOTAL_MANIFESTO] 

FROM RODMAN R
WHERE R.PLACA = 'FRV4H89'
GROUP BY R.PLACA, R.DATEMI
```

O resultado que esta vindo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado que gostaria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Voce está agrupando pela data completa, não pelo mês.

Answer (score -2):

Resolvi o problema utilizando o Format, ficando dessa forma:

```sql
SELECT R.PLACA, FORMAT(R.DATEMI, 'MM/yyyy') AS MES, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_MANIFESTO 
FROM RODMAN AS R 
GROUP BY R.PLACA, FORMAT(R.DATEMI, 'MM/yyyy')
```